# Is it a bug that Quantmod overwrites column names when returning Lag output

Tags: r, quantmod

For example:

```
> col1<-Lag(c(1,2,3))
> col1
     Lag.1
[1,]    NA
[2,]     1
[3,]     2


> df<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3))
> df$a<-Lag(df$a)
> df
  Lag.1
1    NA
2     1
3     2
```

Note that the column headers are `Lag.1` rather than the expected `a`

Comment: It actually doesn't overwrite the names. If you'll notice, `df$a` is now a matrix, so the name `a` was not actually changed.  The structure of the column `a` was changed through the `quantmod:::Lag.numeric` method, and what you are seeing is just due to the print method of data frames.  You can check `c(df)` to see more.

Comment: Yes but if I am storing the result in a dataframe the name changes with no warning whatsoever. This sounds like a problem to me.....

Comment: To clarify, after using `Lag` on `df$a` the column `a` ceases to be callable, it now answers to `Lag.1`

Comment: That's not what happens when I run your example code.  I can still call `df$a`.  Strange.

Comment: Hmm, youre correct.... only the name changes- I thought the entire reference to `df$a` didnt exist anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't specific to quantmod or `Lag`. It's how replacement works with data.frame columns (`$<-.data.frame`). If you replace a column with a 1-column matrix that has a column name, the existing column will be removed and replaced with the new column.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3)
mat <- matrix(3:1, dimnames=list(NULL, "A"))
df$a <- mat
```

If you don't want that to happen, you should `drop` dimensions of the object you're going to use as a replacement.

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3)
df$a <- drop(Lag(df$a))
```